# Label Colorbar of Array Plot

Tags: plotting, legending

How to add label to the colorbar generated using [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) and [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html)

E.g. color represents 'meters'. I would like to add that label next or below the colorbar.

```
x = {{1, 45, 32, 8, 0, 90, 20, 1}, {0.5, 4, 5, 10, 70, 1, 1, 7}};
ArrayPlot[x, PlotLegends -> {Placed[Automatic, Below]}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
x = {{1, 45, 32, 8, 0, 90, 20, 1}, {0.5, 4, 5, 10, 70, 1, 1, 
   7}}; ArrayPlot[x, 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[
    BarLegend[Automatic, Automatic, LegendLabel -> "metres"], Below]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using the third parameter of [`Placed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html) is probably the most direct:

```
x = {{1, 45, 32, 8, 0, 90, 20, 1}, {0.5, 4, 5, 10, 70, 1, 1, 7}};

ArrayPlot[x, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below, Labeled[#, "meters"] &]]
```

[image]

The third parameter of [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) can be used to set the placement of the label, e.g. `Placed[Automatic, Below, Labeled[#, "meters", Right] &]`.  For left or right placement this alternative also works:

```
ArrayPlot[x, PlotLegends -> {Placed[Automatic, Below], Placed["meters", Below]}]
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[x, PlotLegends -> {Placed["meters", Below], Placed[Automatic, Below]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am always missing the natural answer...not sure I will ever learn :( p.s. nice illustration of North America v terra Australis spelling

Comment: @ubpdqn Please do not be disheartened like that.  Your answer is very good and opens to door to more extensive customization.  I already voted for it, as I have for many other answers of yours.

Comment: @ubpdqn See, the OP like your answer better. :-)